# User login API for social login from mobile apps

Tags: 7, users, services, authentication-authorization

I have installed [HybridAuth](https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth) module for social login (Only Facebook & Google) and It is working fine.

I need the same functionality for mobile apps. Like the user can able to login using the social accounts from mobile apps also.

Please suggest me how to do. Is it possible to do with [HybridAuth](https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth) module or I need to do different way?

Comment: Hi All, I am also looking for the same, Please give me some idea to resolve this using  HybridAuth.

Answer (score 3):

I was also looking for functionality that you needs, but after wards i tried to implement service for social sign in using Hybridauth module and i succeed.

Try this https://github.com/rathodhiren9/hybridauth-service.git

**Note** : Its my own implementation and working fine using Poster/Postman. But you need to test in mobile application on your own.

1. Place this module folder in /sites/all/modules/custom and give full permissions if you are using Linux/Unix.
2. Look for Hybridauth Services in you all module list from Admin pannel of drupal 7 and install/activate it.
3. Now goto structure/services and add new endpoint if you don't have (remember Path to endpoint will be used in your URL call of service from mobile app).

[image]

4. After that you need to add Resources as per you requirement and for this service you need to check "hybridauth" resource and "connect" action from available resources and save the configuration.
5. Now this service will work from URL like **/domainname/path-to-endpoint/hybridauth/connect**. Be sure that url of your domain must match with your social media app's url that you are using for facebook or google
6. If your done well all the steps then you surly will test the service from Postman or Poster tools, But you need to get access token which will be an array of user data came from Facebook or Google and you will easily get it by debugging Hybridauth module's hybridauth.pages.inc file.

Hope this may be helpful.

Comment: HI @hiren rathod, I am also tryind to do same thing. Can you please provide the updated code of https://github.com/rathodhiren9/hybridauth-service.git, because in above git file : https://github.com/rathodhiren9/hybridauth-service/blob/master/hybridauth_services/hybridauth_services.resource.inc is empty.

Comment: Any updates? I am also stuck at it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) Drupal module and use the hybridauth endpoint with JSON data.

Comment: Kalpan, could you please explain what the OP meant by mobile apps ? He mentioned that it works only for Facebook & Google, so what are these "mobile apps" ? Thanks,

Comment: Mobile apps can use the endpoint of the REST services made using Services Drupal module. For login using Facebook or Google at Mobile Application one need to configure Service endpoint to bridge the mobile and drupal application to share the session

Comment: Ohhh, these are the mobile versions of Facebook & Google?

Comment: Mobile Andriod or IOS application to connect with your website or server application to login with Facebook or Google.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response Kalpan.

I'm new to services. I'm not clear and don't know how to do. So, can you please explain more regarding this?

Thanks, Selva

Comment: Please refer following guide for more understanding Services Drupal with REST API. https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/services/

Comment: Kalpan, I have basic idea about services and I have created user login/registration and some other API's as well. But, here I can't understand how to use HybridAuth from mobile application.

Thanks, Selva

Comment: Great. All you need to access the Hybridauth end point mobile/hybridauth/connect with JSON data to login with facebook

Comment: Kalpan, I can't access the end point url "mobile/hybridauth/connect". Can you please explain step by step? Like we need to create this resource under existing endpoint or it is predefined? If it is predefined, how can I enable in the services end point section?
Need more help.

Thanks,

Comment: @vgsbharathi This is Q+A - step-by-step guides, tutorials, articles, etc don't suit the format here. You need to narrow your request down to something for which an answer can be summarised in a couple of paragraphs, or break your task down into its smallest parts and research those individually. If you can't find an answer out on the internet after an exhaustive search, that's when to ask here. The [help] has more info on the site and what sort of questions are appropriate

Comment: I dont think hybridauth can be clubbed along with Services to solve the problem here. Hybridauth will put up a "webpage" to get permissions from the user for the app which would not be possible through webservices.